I completely erased my early 2015 Macbook Air's internal disk from an external USB macOS, now the macbook is not powering on
MacOS Yosemite (I know it's very ancient!), in my early 2015 Macbook Air was getting unresponsive within 10-20 seconds after every boot, so it had become literally useless. I had somehow recovered my data from macOS installed on an external USB drive.
I completely erased my early 2015 Macbook Air's internal disk, thinking of doing a fresh installation before selling off the device, just like I would on any other PC. But now the device won't even power up, so that was a mistake.
From what I understand from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/451793/547716, disk0s1 is critical to start the MacBook.
I could have sold the MacBook to an electronics recycling company for $135 USD (equivalent in INR) had it been booting. Everything else worked flawlessly. Now I would only get $2 USD (lol!).
Is there any way I can reinstall the operating system on the internal disk?
Thank you in advance.

Let’s check the hardware first. Follow the instructions at https://support.apple.com/en-us/102550 : Try holding down ‘D’ during boot, and if that fails, Option-D and make sure you’re within a WiFi network.

Your link refers to Apple Silicon Macs, which are different. If it won't boot from an external drive, then I'd suggest there's something seriously wrong with the hardware. (E.g. something other than the disk.)

Even a completely blank drive will show you a "no-boot" icon. While the drives are replaceable  in those Macs (I think OWC has compatible drives) it is likely that, coincidentally to your erasing the drive something else happened to the Mac. So like @Benwiggy said there is likely something seriously wrong beyond a defective or erased drive.

Well, after some days, when I randomly tried to switch on the MacBook, it was booting, and I could boot from an external USB. But for some reason, when I try reinstalling macOS from Recovery, it doesn't show the internal MacBook SSD. I think the SSD has some hardware issues now that it is very old...
